# Ng-Options for objects in an array

Tags: angularjs

Here I have a select, where I want to repeat the contacts on the supplier.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    Hello {{name}}
    
    <div ng-repeat="supplier in suppliers">
        {{supplier.name}}
        
        <select ng-options="contact.id as contact.name for contact in supplier.contacts">
        
        </select>
    </div>
    
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
    
    //app.directive('appDirective', function() {});
    //app.factory('appService', function() {});
    
    app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.name = "dave";
        
        $scope.suppliers = [
          {id: 0, name: "dave", contacts : [
             {id: 0, name: 'c1'},
              {id: 1, name: 'c2'},
              {id: 2, name: 'c3'},
              {id: 3, name: 'c4'},
            ]},
            {id: 1, name: "Steve", contacts : [
             {id: 0, name: 'c1'},
              {id: 1, name: 'c2'},
              {id: 2, name: 'c3'},
              {id: 3, name: 'c4'},
            ]}
        ]
    }]);

</script>
```

Here I have the controller.

How come this doesn't seem to work?

http://jsfiddle.net/gnosticdave/091vpadb/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`contacts` is part of each `supplier` - so your array is actually `supplier.contacts`

```
select ng-options="contact.id as contact.name for contact in supplier.contacts"
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also, `ngOptions` needs an `ngModel`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/091vpadb/3/

Comment: Ng-model fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<select ng-options="contact.id as contact.name for contact in contacts">
```

to:

```
<select ng-options="contact.id as contact.name for contact in supplier.contacts">
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put that in my code, but even with it, its still not working.